# How to get NAN when downsampling with last

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, resampling

I want to downsample some time series data, giving me the last value of each quarter:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

index = pd.date_range(start='2020', freq='M', periods=6)
data = np.ones(6)
data[4:6] = np.nan

datetime
2020-01-31    1.0
2020-02-29    1.0
2020-03-31    1.0
2020-04-30    1.0
2020-05-31    NaN
2020-06-30    NaN
Freq: M, dtype: float64
```

My requirement is that if the last value is nan, the downsampled value should also be nan, not the last non-nan value in the segment.
Here that would be a 1.0 as of 4/30, we dont want that. We want NAN for Q2.

According to the documentation, you can use .last() with the "min_count" keyword, but in reality that fails - bug report with pandas pending. That is besides the issue.

```
datetime.resample('Q').last(min_count=3)
```

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-bd5dfd934676> in <module>
----> 1 datetime.resample('Q').last(min_count=3)

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/resample.py in g(self, _method, *args, **kwargs)
    934 
    935     def g(self, _method=method, *args, **kwargs):
--> 936         nv.validate_resampler_func(_method, args, kwargs)
    937         return self._downsample(_method)
    938 

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/compat/numpy/function.py in validate_resampler_func(method, args, kwargs)
    383             )
    384         else:
--> 385             raise TypeError("too many arguments passed in")
    386 
    387 

TypeError: too many arguments passed in
```

Until that is resolved, how can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Looks like `datetime[datetime.resample('Q').last().index]`?

Comment: interesting. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Trying to understand the comment, I think it uses the index of the last record of the bin. This works with quarters. My example was not exactly correct, I figured it makes no difference. But quarterly downsampling uses the last data point as label. Lower timeframes do not. So I think it would not work with eg. minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An enhancement is probable which will address this:
[Github issue #37768](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/37768)

In the meantime, here is a workaround:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(datetime,columns =['data'])
df.fillna(1234.56789, inplace=True)  # unique and not in your data
df2 = df.resample('Q').last()
df2['data']=np.where(df2['data']==1234.56789,
                    np.nan,
                    df2['data'])

df2

data
2020-03-31  1.0
2020-06-30  NaN
```